# No PhD research group during my PhD. How do I handle it?

Tags: phd, research-group

I have been involved in my PhD now for about half a year but my setup is potentially more uncommon. It feels very independent because I havent got a research group I'm involved in at all. It's literally just me and two of my supervisors and I work in a completely separate building to both of them and I have absolutely no one to collaborate with or talk to about my research or ask for help. Is anyone else in this same or similar situation and if so/or do you have any advice on how I could improve my work situation because at the moment it feels very lonely and when I get stuck there is no one around to ask.

Comment: Obvious improvement: can you push to move to the building where your supervisors are? Presumably there are more people working on something related there.

Comment: Have you spoken about this with your supervisors? If they're similarly isolated then they may know of people, either in your institution or in a wider network, that you haven't thought of.

Comment: Depends heavily on your field of study.  For example: Presumably a Ph.D. in French Literature is normally done without a research group.

Comment: How is that "uncommon"? It surely depends strongly on the field but in areas like mathematics or phyiscs besides going to conferences from time to time it's essentially you and yourself trying to figure things out.

Comment: Of course I've tried to move closer but there's "no space" apparently and there aren't many people working in my area in the university. I've made contact with two PhD students now who do work slightly in my field so hopefully that'll help! I work in science, engineering/maths/chemistry/physics sort of field so in my opinion science really involves collaboration and ideas from more than one person, especially if you want to learn new techniques. I thought it was uncommon because I have several friends doing science PhD's elsewhere and they all have very nicely setup research groups!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two years, it was just me and my advisor. We were in the same building, but nobody else did anything like our work in our department. It's hard.

I would suggest looking for ways to branch out--particularly at your institution. You'll need committee members. Start looking early. Presumably there are some people in your department (or another department?) who do something tangentially related. Try to get their input at least once per semester so that you keep the lines of communication open.

Try to network with others in your subfield. If there really is a dearth of people you can talk to at your institution, you'll need to look beyond it. Ask your advisor(s?) if they would be willing to introduce you to some individuals. Going to a conference is excellent for this. (Some believe it's worth going to at least one or two conferences per year as a grad student even if you aren't presenting, and even if you have to pay for it yourself!) Networking beyond your institution has numerous benefits after graduation, as you can imagine. You could also do this by sneakily asking really good questions to a select few people who publish in your field (most journal articles include contact info).

The above approaches are aimed at finding people you can talk about your research with. We're not merely research-bots, however. Loneliness in general is a real problem that hinders a lot of grad students in a lot of ways (e.g. imposter syndrome, depression, and so much more). Grads who are already isolated from others (grads and/or advisors) are often more prone to it than others. Research aside, I would make sure that you have friends at your institution that can relate with you. They may be able to give better, institution-specific advice for you as well. I was part of a group of grads from a variety of departments. Their friendship and support was what got me through grad school.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Besides the obvious answers (try to move closer to the place where your supervisors and their groups are and meet them more often) I suggest

**try to find or initiate a seminar close to your interests.**

This would provide a regular meeting point for you and your supervisors (besides meetings directly related to your PhD) and hopefully other people with interests similar to yours. Your supervisors may help to find a theme and spread the word (and probably take formal responsibility for the seminar) but you can and should offer to organize the schedule and the collection and circulation of abstracts.

Comment: This approach seems the best option-regular meeting once or twice per week with different peers.